# How to Data Binding RibbonComboBox?

Tags: wpf

I am using wpf 4 and the Microsoft Ribbon. My binding shows the names of each user in the Users list but the selection is not showing in the RibbonComboBox after the drop down closes.

Thanks

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you mean? Your question is confusing to me, and without any visuals, I don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

XAML:

```
 ...

 <r:RibbonComboBox IsEditable="True">
     <r:RibbonGallery >
         <r:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="userBox" />
     </r:RibbonGallery>
 </r:RibbonComboBox>

...
```

C#

```
...

userBox.ItemsSource = LoadComboBoxUser();

...
```