# How to bind list from database into RibbonComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I have function that return list of strings from database. I want to show those results in wpf ribbon menu.

I think that I need to use `RibbonComboBox` with `RibbonGalleryCategory` and bind `RibbonGalleryItem` somehow to show resulats from db.

Code of my db function looks like that:

```
    public List<String> GetSeanceListName()
    {
        List<String> seanceList = new List<String>();
        seanceList = (from s in Db.Seance
                          where s.Date >= DateTime.Today
                      select s.Name).ToList();

        return seanceList;
    }
```

Any help here much appreciated!

Comment: Cassandra have a look at this one, hopefully helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700696/bind-ribboncombobox-selectionboxitem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Data Binding RibbonComboBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237319/how-to-data-binding-ribboncombobox)

Comment: Thanks for help! And yes you are right - it seems like a duplicate. Answer from this question worked for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox IsEditable="True">
   <ribbon:RibbonGallery>
       <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="seanceList"/>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```